# Make Scala 3 default in CLI

Tags: scala, scala-3

I've just installed Scala 3 on a brand Ubuntu machine. I used Coursier to install Scala 3 using the [official instructions](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/scala3.html).

I can compile a file using `scala3-compiler`, but how do I run it? Using the `scala` command will still default to the 2.13 version of Scala.

Comment: Place the directory of the Scala-3 executable into your `PATH` earlier than the directory of the Scala-2 executable.

Comment: Use `scala3-repl`

Comment: Thanks, but neither is these solves the problem

Comment: Please clarify. How was your `PATH` modified? Did you try to invoke the executable via a full path (i.e. no `PATH`)?

Answer (score 0):

Editing **~/.profile** file in a section '**coursier install directory**' helps.
Initially, the line looks as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/share/coursier/bin"
```

It should be changed to:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/share/coursier/bin:$PATH"
```

Coursiers **bin** directory should be defined earlier, since **bash** picks up the first occurrence of the command among directories defined in **PATH** environment variable.